# Convert date to PostgreSQL syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-arithmetic

The following logic in SQL Server needs to be converted appropriately to PostgreSQL syntax. Please helpm me convert this over to the correct syntax so I can use it in PostgreSQL database:

```
  convert(DATE, dateadd(m, -17, convert(DATE, getdate())))
```

Comment: @JeffModen: look at the tooltip for the downvote button "*does not show any research effort*" would be a pretty good fit.

Answer (score 0):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58d47914db4e55c1c87bf825fa3add1b)

This subtracts 17 months from your date.

```
SELECT
    current_date + interval '-17 months'
```

Comment: this currently throws an error but if I run just the select with what you just provided it is fine

Comment: SELECT aa4.calendar
FROM ods.dim_day as cc
LEFT JOIN edw.dim_day as aa4
   ON cc.day_of_first_month = aa4.date_id
WHERE cc.calendar = (SELECT NOW() + interval '-17 months')

Comment: @an1234 If that worked, please don't forget to accept (to show, that the question has been resolved) and upvote any helpful answer (to honor the work of the repliers).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is:

```
current_date - interval '17 month'
```

It is curious that the SQL Server code converts to `date` twice.